# "point of view" vs "approach"

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I'm writing a document in which I need to state that my work is unsupervised instead of supervised. I have thought in these two sentences, but don't know whether they are correct, or whether is there a better one to explain this situation.

"from an unsupervised decision making point of view"

"with an unsupervised decision making approach"

also, what's the correct way, "decision making" or "decision-making"?

Comment: Please can you give us the whole sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough without knowing the full context, but I believe "from an unsupervised decision-making point of view" is the best option. However, if your approach to decision-making depends on whether you are supervised, the other phrase might also be appropriate.

"Decision-making" is used as a compound adjective here, so it should be hyphenated.

Comment: I'm talking about an algorithm for artificial intelligence, so by unsupervised I mean the algorithm, not me. Now that you know the context, Is it still the one with "point of view" the best sentence?

Comment: Does the algorithm use a different strategy if it is supervised? If so, then approach is good. Otherwise, I prefer "point of view".

Comment: Why not use "perspective" instead of point of view?

Comment: in AI there are algorithms which are supervised (i.e. there is a human behind which decides what to do with the output data) and unsupervised (i.e. the algorithm takes action without human consent)

Comment: In that case, I think "approach" is best. 

@shaunxer, I this "from... a perspective" is a good alternative to POV, depending on the formality of the writing. Considering this is about an algorithm, it's probably preferable to POV.